# How to move my Canadian stocks into RRSP

Tags: canada, rrsp, transfer

I have various stocks I hold for the dividends (and most are DRIPs). They are NOT in any tax-advantaged accounts.

Is there an easy way to move them into, say, an RRSP? Or would I be required to sell the shares and repurchase them?

My goal is to offset my yearly tax bill by stashing it in my RRSP; my TFSA is maxed out each year.